# Why does new File(path) doesn't work when I run my application from jar?

Tags: java, file, jar, filenotfoundexception

Why does `new File(path)` doesn't work when I run my application from jar? How should I change this? Now I'm receiving `FileNotFound` Exception when my application tries to load a file.

```
final File file = new File("src/main/resources/maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp");
```

Comment: Provide more details, how are giving the path? is it relative? etc.

Comment: it works fine from eclipse but when i execute java - jar in cmd it raises exception.

Comment: I am creating that file in the main method. I used maven shade plugin. When I unpack my jar, map folder is next to the folder of a package that contains class where I create file. I tried with new File(object.getClass().getResources("maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp").getPath()) but i got null pointer exception.

Comment: can you unzip the jar and see (1) if the file is actually getting included, (2) what is it's location. Ideally, the `maps` folder will be on the first level, under that you will have your `shp` file. If so you should be able to get it's URL using `obj.getClass().getResource("/maps/fileName")`

Comment: ah, I see error in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If jar created properly, say using Maven, the resources files goes next to class files. It looks something like this:

```
myapp.jar
 |
 +--- com
 |     +---mycompany
 |            +-- FileOpsClass
 |
 +--- maps
        +-- fileToRead
```

you can either walk up in directory and access `fileToRead`, like this for above structure:

```
  final File file = new File("../../maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp");
```

or as suggested

```
  final File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is already in the classpath you can get it like this:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("Relative_Path_From_This_Class_To_YourFileName").getPath());
```

Answer (score 1):

When running eclipse the current working directory is set to the project directory. Hence the relative path works. As the file is zipped into the jar too, better use an InputStream instead of a file.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp");
```